# ClipPlanes on Translated 3D objects crash front end

Tags: front-end, bugs, graphics3d, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and fixed in V11.0 (at least Win)**

---

Applying `Translate` to a simple 3D object (e.g. `Pyramid`) along with using the `ClipPlane` crashes FrontEnd with "Mathematica has stopped working". It seems to be OK in 10.0.2.0. Without the `Translate` or `ClipPlane` it works fine. I am on Win7-64bit.

```
Graphics3D[
 Translate[
  Pyramid[{{-0.24, -0.24, 0.}, {0.24, -0.24, 0.}, {0.24, 0.24, 0.}, 
           {-0.24, 0.24, 0.}, {0., 0., -0.32}}],
  {0, 0, 0.06}
 ],
 ClipPlanes -> {{0., -1, 0., 0.08}}
]
```

Comment: I can confirm that the above code crashes the kernel *and the front-end* immediately and irreparably, whereas it works just fine without the `ClipPlanes` option. I am on MMA 10.2. Win7-64bit.

Comment: Total crash also for me with v10.2, OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Crash on 10.2, linux too.

Comment: I have tagged this with [tag:bugs] because it has sufficient confirmation

Comment: I can reproduce this on V10.1, too.  In V10.0, the code executes and I can executes other commands after, but I get a crash on quitting (usually). Also, I changed the tags/header to conform to [meta/q/1610](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching).

Comment: It crashes the front end, not the kernel.

Comment: No crash for me on OSX, Mma v10.4.

Comment: NO more crash for me also on OSX (10.9.5) with v10.4.0 & 10.4.1. (With v10.3.1 it still crashes FE+Ker.)

Comment: Just checked with Wolfram - they say status is that it is still unresolved for 10.4 (must only be on WinTel platforms)

Comment: Fixed on Windows as of v11.0.

Answer (score 2):

> Fixed on Windows as of V11.0.
>
> – user31159 Aug 24 '16 at 0:07

(*wiki answer to remove it from unanswered stack*)