# Slicing an angled Tube or Cylinder so the top is flat

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

I'm trying to create a graphic for an inclined manometer and need to make the fluid in the manometer tube look realistic. The part where the blue and green tubes meet should be flat, like a real liquid. The red disk at that point represents what I need it to look like.

[image]

[image]

The angle is changed with a slider in `Manipulate`. I tried to make the solutions from this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79913/how-do-i-plot-a-filled-cylinder-in-3d) work but failed. How can I take a slice out of a tube/cylinder that is at an angle?

Here is my code to work from to make the graphic:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   Blue,
   Tube[{{-2.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {10*Cos[theta], 0, 10*Sin[theta]}}, 
    1.25],

   Green,
   Tube[{{10*Cos[theta], 0, 10*Sin[theta]}, {15*Cos[theta], 0, 
      15*Sin[theta]}, {15*Cos[theta] + 2.5, 0, 15*Sin[theta]}}, 1.25],

   }, ViewPoint -> Front],
 Control[{{theta, Pi/6}, Pi/6, Pi/4}]
 ]
```

Comment: `Tube[]` itself can't be cut off, so starting from lower-level primitives (i.e. `Polygon[]`) would be necessary here. Are those bends needed, or are you fine with a solution that just generates a truncated cylinder?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `ClipPlanes` option. For example:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{
    Style[
      Tube[{{-2.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {15*Cos[theta], 0, 15*Sin[theta]}}, 1.25],
      Blue,
      ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 10*Sin[theta]},
        {1, 0, 10*Sin[theta]}, {0, -1, 10*Sin[theta]}}]
    ],
    Style[
      Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {15*Cos[theta], 0, 15*Sin[theta]},
        {15*Cos[theta] + 2.5, 0, 15*Sin[theta]}}, 1.25],
      Green,
      ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 10*Sin[theta]},
        {1, 0, 10*Sin[theta]}, {0, 1, 10*Sin[theta]}}]
    ]
  }, ViewPoint -> Front],
Control[{{theta, Pi/6}, Pi/6, Pi/4}]]
```

[image: ClipPlanes]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working as shown in version 10.1.0; do you happen to know if it should?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `ClipPlanes` on version 10 [was a bit shaky](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94496/27951). The documentation reports that it was introduced in 10.0, but updated in version 11; I wonder if the problem you see might be related to its earlier unreliability. The code works well in my v.11.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think in v.10 you can cut Tubes only once. Here, we cut one Tube with one plane, and a second one with another and combine it in `Graphics3D`. Try this code in v.10: `Graphics3D[{Tube[{{-2.5, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {15*Cos[theta], 0, 
     15*Sin[theta]}}, 1.25]}, 
 ClipPlanes -> 
  InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 10*Sin[theta]}, {1, 0, 10*Sin[theta]}, {0, -1,
      10*Sin[theta]}}]]` It will probably work, but I think you won't be able to combine two cut tubes...